# Can I fetch details of the incoming call phone number in my applicaton?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, phone-call

Can I fetch details of the incoming call phone number in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't and for good reason Apple does not enable applications to snoop on the phone calls the user makes.